# remove exponents from a formula string

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

I would like to isolate all operands from a formula (in the form of a string) by taking out the arithmetic operators so take out: "+","-","/","*","**2"
the formula string is something like:

```
"y=A+B1*options+B2*items**2+B3*factor+B4"
```

However: I can manage for most arithmetic operators, except for the exponents "**2" part. It has to be a wildcard search or so (not positional), because the whole formula might change in future and also might have another exponent (eg **5 or **54)

What would be the easiest way to strip "**?" out of the formula where ? can be any number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the pattern you want, use the regex string `r"\*\*\d+"` 
Breakdown:

- `r""` is the how one denotes regex in python (see the `re` module for more info)
- `\*` matches a single `*` character - because the `*` is a special character in regex, we escape it with the `\`
- `\d` matches a digit
- `+` matches the previous pattern at least once greedily: this means it will try to find at least one digit, then keep finding digits until it can find no more. So, it will match `**2`, `**44382`, and so on

As for stripping the pattern from the equation, you can do `re.sub(pattern, "", equation)` - replacing all instances of the pattern with nothing